# cannot receive raw ethernet frame packets I just sent

Tags: sockets, frame, ethernet

I referenced C code on this website: https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/2862515

Here is a image to explain:

[image]

I edit it at two parts, one pat is for ethertype（change 0x0800 to a custom-protocol 0x1234）
and another part is deleting code for IP header processing (because original code is based on IP, but I need a raw ethernet frame).

I used wireshark to detect packets, and I can receive the packets I sent（in left of image）,and I can see send.out exactly sending packets(bottom right of image). But recv.out cannot receive packet !?(upper right of image).

However, if I use 0x0800 for protocol, recv.out can receive packets from outside, but still cannot receive the packets I sent.

Is there any mistake for setting socket

Here is my code:

send.c

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>

#define MY_DEST_MAC0    0xbc
#define MY_DEST_MAC1    0xee
#define MY_DEST_MAC2    0x7b
#define MY_DEST_MAC3    0x75
#define MY_DEST_MAC4    0x56
#define MY_DEST_MAC5    0x2a

#define DEFAULT_IF  "eth0"
#define BUF_SIZ     1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct ifreq if_idx;
    struct ifreq if_mac;
    int tx_len = 0;
    char sendbuf[BUF_SIZ];
    struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf; /*structure*/
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header));
    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
    char ifName[IFNAMSIZ];

    unsigned short proto = 0x1234;

    /* Get interface name *//*eth0*/
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(ifName, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(ifName, DEFAULT_IF);

    /* Open RAW socket to send on *//*IPv4*/
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(proto))) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
    }

    /* Get the index of the interface to send on *//*0*/
    memset(&if_idx, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_idx.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx) < 0)/*save INDEX info into if_idx*/
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
    /* Get the MAC address of the interface to send on *//*local*//*save MAC info into if_mac*/
    memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac) < 0)
        perror("SIOCGIFHWADDR");

    /* Construct the Ethernet header */
    memset(sendbuf, 0, BUF_SIZ);
    /* Ethernet header */
    eh->ether_shost[0] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[0];
    eh->ether_shost[1] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[1];
    eh->ether_shost[2] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[2];
    eh->ether_shost[3] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[3];
    eh->ether_shost[4] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[4];
    eh->ether_shost[5] = ((uint8_t *)&if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)[5];
    eh->ether_dhost[0] = MY_DEST_MAC0;
    eh->ether_dhost[1] = MY_DEST_MAC1;
    eh->ether_dhost[2] = MY_DEST_MAC2;
    eh->ether_dhost[3] = MY_DEST_MAC3;
    eh->ether_dhost[4] = MY_DEST_MAC4;
    eh->ether_dhost[5] = MY_DEST_MAC5;
    /* Ethertype field */
    eh->ether_type = htons(proto);
    tx_len += sizeof(struct ether_header);

    /* Packet data */
    sendbuf[tx_len++] = "h";
    sendbuf[tx_len++] = "e";
    sendbuf[tx_len++] = "l";
    sendbuf[tx_len++] = "l";
    sendbuf[tx_len++] = "o";

    /* Index of the network device */
    socket_address.sll_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
    /* Address length*/
    socket_address.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
    /* Destination MAC */
    socket_address.sll_addr[0] = MY_DEST_MAC0;
    socket_address.sll_addr[1] = MY_DEST_MAC1;
    socket_address.sll_addr[2] = MY_DEST_MAC2;
    socket_address.sll_addr[3] = MY_DEST_MAC3;
    socket_address.sll_addr[4] = MY_DEST_MAC4;
    socket_address.sll_addr[5] = MY_DEST_MAC5;

    /* Send packet */
int cnt=0;
while(cnt<5){
    if (sendto(sockfd, sendbuf, tx_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) < 0)
        printf("Send failed\n");
    else
        printf("success!\n");

    cnt++;
}
    return 0;

}
```

recv.c

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>

#define DEST_MAC0   0xbc
#define DEST_MAC1   0xee
#define DEST_MAC2   0x7b
#define DEST_MAC3   0x75
#define DEST_MAC4   0x56
#define DEST_MAC5   0x2a

#define ETHER_TYPE  0x1234

#define DEFAULT_IF  "eth0"
#define BUF_SIZ     1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char sender[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int sockfd, ret, i;
    int sockopt;
    ssize_t numbytes;
    struct ifreq ifopts;    /* set promiscuous mode */
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    uint8_t buf[BUF_SIZ];
    char ifName[IFNAMSIZ];

    /* Get interface name *//*eth0*/
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(ifName, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(ifName, DEFAULT_IF);

    /* Header structures */
    struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) buf;

    /* Open PF_PACKET socket, listening for EtherType ETHER_TYPE *//*0x1234*/
    if ((sockfd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETHER_TYPE))) == -1) {
        perror("listener: socket"); 
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set interface to promiscuous mode - do we need to do this every time? *//*cpy ifname into ifr_name*/
    strncpy(ifopts.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifopts); /*set promisc mode*/
    ifopts.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
    ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifopts);
    /* Allow the socket to be reused - incase connection is closed prematurely */
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &sockopt, sizeof sockopt) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Bind to device */
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1) == -1)  {
        perror("SO_BINDTODEVICE");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

repeat: printf("listener: Waiting to recvfrom...\n");
    numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUF_SIZ, 0, NULL, NULL);
    printf("listener: got packet %lu bytes\n", numbytes);

    /* Check the packet is for me */
    if (eh->ether_dhost[0] == DEST_MAC0 &&
            eh->ether_dhost[1] == DEST_MAC1 &&
            eh->ether_dhost[2] == DEST_MAC2 &&
            eh->ether_dhost[3] == DEST_MAC3 &&
            eh->ether_dhost[4] == DEST_MAC4 &&
            eh->ether_dhost[5] == DEST_MAC5) {
        printf("Correct destination MAC address\n");
    } else {
        printf("Wrong destination MAC: %x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\n",
                        eh->ether_dhost[0],
                        eh->ether_dhost[1],
                        eh->ether_dhost[2],
                        eh->ether_dhost[3],
                        eh->ether_dhost[4],
                        eh->ether_dhost[5]);
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

    /* Print packet */
    printf("\tData:");
    for (i=0; i<numbytes; i++) printf("%02x:", buf[i]);
    printf("\n");

done:   goto repeat;

    close(sockfd);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get All frames from your target with below changes in your receive code :

please replace line :
`if ((sockfd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETHER_TYPE))) == -1) {`

with this line :
`if ((sockfd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) == -1) {`

Because in your original code you changed normal ethernet header type then OS can not detect its process listener(your program) and get it to you but when you set this line, OS can get you all results so you can get your special answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to do socket programming so someone should confirm this.

I'm pretty sure the interface will drop the packet because the source and destination mac are the same... try using another PC and change the destination mac on each side to confirm this (virtual machines work as well)

Answer (score 0):

I have also used a similar code to transfer Ethernet frames. This type of socket does not  work locally. As @Goncalo suggested use a different PC or if you have two NICs on your PC you should use them. Here is the Code I used to receive Frames.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>    
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

union ethframe
{
  struct
  {
    struct ethhdr    header;
    unsigned char    data[ETH_DATA_LEN];
  } field;
  unsigned char    buffer[ETH_FRAME_LEN];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *iface = "eth1";
  unsigned char dest[ETH_ALEN]     
          = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
  unsigned short proto = 0x1234;
  int recv_result,i;
  char buff[ETH_FRAME_LEN];
  unsigned short data_len;

  int s;
  if ((s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(proto))) < 0) {
    printf("Error: could not open socket\n");
    return -1;
  }

  struct ifreq buffer;
  int ifindex;
  memset(&buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer));
  strncpy(buffer.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ);
  if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &buffer) < 0) {
    printf("Error: could not get interface index\n");
    close(s);
    return -1;
  }
  ifindex = buffer.ifr_ifindex;

  unsigned char source[ETH_ALEN];
  if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &buffer) < 0) {
    printf("Error: could not get interface address\n");
    close(s);
    return -1;
  }
  memcpy((void*)source, (void*)(buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data),
         ETH_ALEN);


  struct sockaddr_ll saddrll;
  memset((void*)&saddrll, 0, sizeof(saddrll));
  saddrll.sll_family = PF_PACKET;   
  saddrll.sll_ifindex = ifindex;
  saddrll.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
  memcpy((void*)(saddrll.sll_addr), (void*)dest, ETH_ALEN);

  socklen_t sll_len = (socklen_t)sizeof(saddrll);  

  if (recv_result = recvfrom(s, buff, ETH_FRAME_LEN, 0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&saddrll, &sll_len) > 0)
    printf("Success!\n");
  else
    printf("Error, could not send\n");

  data_len=sizeof(buff);
  printf("\tData:");
    for (i=0; i<data_len; i++) printf("%c", buff[i]);


  printf("\tDone: \n");
  close(s);

  return 0;
}
```